# How to add screen to view instance logs in Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I tried to add screen to view instance logs but it can't work. I watched in GitHub https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/pull/168/files but it like old version because some file is not exist.
Somebody can help me! Thank for your help!

Comment: Please edit your question with more details like which version, what you have tried and how it failed. How is it different from the existing logs screen? https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/tree/main/src/main/webapp/app/admin/logs Also in JHipster v7, this feature will be part of JHipster Control Center https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-control-center

Comment: I apologize for this inconvenience. I have tried to do adding modules to display the logfile field in the admin following sample post (Jhipster 6.10 + Angular): https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry but it always fails with error 
No pipe found with name 'groupBy'.
 8             <div *ngFor="let app of routes | groupBy : 'appName'">
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit your question rather than commenting, it's more readable for code. You did not answer my other questions